# Firebase does not work with multiple apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working with firebase and I created one project and linked two application for this same firebase project. I create a login and sign in screens using Firebase Auth.

But the problem is that in the first application I linked, the sign in works as expected but in the second app, after I click on register, the callback is never complete and the user is never created. This is the method I using from both:

```
public void bntRegistrarRClick(View v)
    {
        (firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txtEmail.getText().toString(), txtSenha.getText().toString())).
                addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(RegistroActivity.this, "Registrado com Sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(RegistroActivity.this, CreateProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e("ERROR", task.getException().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(RegistroActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
```

The android applications are in different projects.

Someone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the applications to the same project. In this way, I was able to connect and use firebase for both since the applications share the same database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven'd added another app details into the firebase existing app for first one. 
From Android Studio go to Tools->Firebase and create, add apps to project of choice.

Add all your android app into the same firebase app.